what percentage of patent applications to the USPTO contain typos or errors?
I am curious to know at least an estimate of this number. If there are more precise breakdown of the kind of errors and typos that would be appreciated as well.

I would try googling - I found an article with the title “ Investigating the Impacts of Misspellings in Patent Search by Combining Natural Language Tools and Rule-Based . . . “

My guess is virtually all of them have some insignificant typo.
